# Database Classes and bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I usually connect and utilize my database through functions.
I wanted to use a class to make life easier this time around.
I am not getting any errors but have concerns.
I have 2 questions about my code.

1. Are the bind parameters I'm passing into execute actually being bound? Or is it just variable substitution.
2. I read that bound parameter values need to be passed by reference or there will be an error. I am not getting one.

```
class Database
{
    protected $dbservername = "localhost";

    protected $dbusername = "root";

    protected $dbpassword = "";

    protected $dbname = "systemdb";

    protected $stmt = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbservername;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbusername, $this->dbpassword);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // echo "Connected successfully";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // receive the query and bindParam as an array
    public function query($q, $args = [])
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($q);
        $this->stmt->execute($args);
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    // return one row of results
    public function getter()
    {
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

```
//------Here is the webpage----

$db = new Database();

$q = 'SELECT firstName, lastName FROM person WHERE personId=:personId';
$numResults = $db->query($q, [":personId" => 22]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++) {
    $row = $db->getter();
    echo $row["firstName"];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

```
//------another Class option to assure binding---------
public function query($q, $args = [])
{
    $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($q);
    foreach ($arg as $key => $value) {
        $this->stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    $this->stmt->execute($args);
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: I don't get what your questions have to do with the fact that you started using classes

Comment: Answers: 1. It's just variable substitution. To enable native parameter binding you have to disable emulated prepares. 2. Passing by reference is not required. It's an optional feature if you use `bindParam()` method.

Comment: @Dharman I don't understand why your comment doesn't address the questions.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: What is the benefit of native parameter binding? I don't believe there is much of a difference in security. To my knowledge, the only difference is the query statement is not sent to the server in advance. Doesn't native binding slow down response time? I also think I'd have to do a major rewrite, doesn't native binding only allow positional parameters? I used named parameters everywhere.

Comment: Technically, native prepared statements are the most secure option. Emulated prepares are also secure, but for example you forgot to set a charset. This could result potentially in SQL injection or other errors. However, emulated prepares have other downsides which you might want to research. It's mostly a matter of choice. There's barely any difference in performance. Definitely you won't notice any difference. Native prepares also allow named parameters so you won't have to change much.

Comment: With native prepares I believe there is double communication with the server for every query. Not too high a cost now-a-days I guess. So if I decide to stick with the emulated prepares, can I just use the code at the bottom of my submission to bind the para,eters separately? I have always done it that way with functions. Me being new to database classes is the reason for my questions... in a response to your first comment. When you're doing something new, you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: You'll be fine but use one style of binding parameters. Either use the `foreach` loop or pass the array to `execute()`. I prefer the execute method as it is much easier to pass parameters. This is just usual PDO, the fact that you are creating classes in your code has no impact on how you use PDO.

Comment: So, last question. If in my code above, where I'm passing the parameters in the execute, you said they weren't being bound. How can I pass in the bound versions? I've always done the bindParam version as seen in my for loop. I'd like to learn something new.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `bindParam` or `execute` the result is exactly the same. In emulated prepares mode variables are properly formatted and interpolated into the query. In native prepares mode, the variables are bound to the prepared statement. Here is a proper explanation https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation